# Why does an ASCX control throws a 404 error?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, iis-7.5, ascx

I have created a simple user control, and added it in an aspx page.
I have registered it within the page as follows...

```
<%@ Register src="faq.ascx" tagname="faq" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

The problem is that on localhost it works like a charm, but when i uploaad it to the live environment (IIS 7.5) i get the 404 error. Is there any setting in web.config that i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use path to your ascx control this way:

```
<%@ Register src="~/faq.ascx" tagname="faq" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

or

```
<%@ Register src="~/some_path/faq.ascx" tagname="faq" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

OR

Maybe you are using some url rewriting module or something similar, which blocked (or rewrite) path to you faq.ascx file.

Try Fiddler application to recognize http requests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 404 is occurred when I forgot to upload the ascx.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be caused if there is not an event with the same name in the code behind, for example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false"
                OnClick="btnCancel1_Click" CssClass="btn-cancel" />
```

If btnCancel1_Click does not exist in the code behind, you will get this error.